# Cocos2D find out the layer which is being used among several layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi guys
      I am new to the cocos2D.In my game i have one scene and several layer to display Menu,pause,level finish,game over. now i want to find out the layer which is being used on top of the scene. i already tried and got the solution to solve it by using boolean variable for every layer. but this is not a good way to use i thought.
please provide some suggestions

Thanks 
Riash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply keep a pointer to the active layer. And it is better to have different scenes for every game state because in this case your management will become much simpler. That's because typically your game scene will have more then one layer. For example: background, level objects, controls and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response i am new to cocos2D.how to keep a pointer to the current layer.i think creating a cclayer object which holds the current layer object . just assigning the pointer. is it correct

Comment: yep. In header file in your class fields write: CCLayer *currentLayer_; Then in .mm file currentLayer_ = [[CCLayer alloc] init]; or assign to any other CCLayer pointer